# Audio playing only on right side on my Galaxy S3

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio

I'm using Cyanogenmod cm-10.1.0-RC1 on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (at&t US version)

With either a headset or bluetooth, I'm only getting audio from the right side. It doesn't matter which output device I use - all are only playing on the right side.

Is this a known issue with CM RC1 or is something else causing this problem?

The getprop("ro.bootloader") checks are all failing for the nightly builds, so updating after RC1 has been problematic. However, if RC1 is the culprit, I'll take extreme measures to update to a different CM version.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with google music. If you move the music slider to a different position, it will output sound on both sides, but the bug appears again once it changes track.

I believe this is a bug on Cyanogenmod 10.1 RC1. I just updated to RC4 and the bug seems fixed. Yay!

Comment: I was just going to mention that you're correct - it was a bug in 10.1 RC1. I was able to update to RC2, which fixed the problem, but unfortunately had the same getprop() errors for RC3 and RC4. Thanks for the reply. Now I just need to figure out how to get to the latest RC!

Comment: How did you update from RC1 or RC2 to RC4?

Comment: You go to Settings > About Phone > CynanogenMod Updates to check for updates. I selected for stable release only and RC4 popped up. RC4 was released like a week ago. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update to RC2 which fixed the bug introduced in RC1. As I mentioned in the comment to @mohdyusuf unfortunately I can't upgrade beyond RC2 now, due to the same "getprop()" errors mentioned in my question. But at least the right-side audio problem is resolved with RC2.